# Wesbite super slow on iphone / very fast on desktop with same connection on wifi

Tags: css, iphone

I'm having an issue on my website.

The speed is perfect on desktop - really fast.

However - it is really really slow in Iphone/Ipad.

THe thing is im using the same connexion wifi - soit's not related to the 3G/4G connextion.

( tried in different place e- also tried in 3G / 4G ).

Do you have any idea why is this happening ?

I'm using W3 Total Cache and it doenst change anything .. .

Hope to have some highlite , thank you your time guys !

Comment: Why do you suspect _WP_ to be involved? You might want to look at this as more generic performance issue. Also the link to actual site would be helpful. :)

Comment: Hi,

Well, it's just the website is done with wordpress.

AS generic performance issue, what do you mean ?

May it be realted to the server? Running Apache on Centos

Comment: Well, the output of front end is essentially the _theme_ rather than WordPress. It might be asset-related, it might be JS-related, it might be server related...